# Why do we need to double define variables passing from main to methods?

Tags: java, variables, methods, parameters

Take the following code:

```
public static void print(ArrayList<String> list) {
    for (String word : list) {
        System.out.println( word );
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Java");
    list.add("Python");
    list.add("Ruby");
    list.add("C++");

    print(list);
}
```

Why do we need to define 'list' as an ArrayList in main, and then define it again in the parameters in the method? Why can't the variable type be passed from main to method? Any way to do this? Any examples in which you'd want the type to change between main and method?

It feels like having to unnecessarily do the same step twice.

For example, why can't we just use:

```
public static void print(list) {
    for (String word : list) {
        System.out.println( word );
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Java");
    list.add("Python");
    list.add("Ruby");
    list.add("C++");

    print(list);
}
```

Comment: You're asking why you need to specify the type both times?

Comment: Because you don't have to call `print` from this `main` method.

Comment: Basically syntax.  The language spec says you have to.  All method parameters must have a specified type.  You'll understand better once you write more code, I expect, but for now you'll just have to accept it.

Comment: The parameter type of the method cannot be derived from the variable in `main` because the method exists independently of `main`, and `main` may not even be the only caller. Java is a statically-typed language, so the parameter **must** have a well-defined type.

Comment: You might declare it public or in constructor or static. So it all depends how you are coding. You wont have to pass in the parameter even.

Comment: Then you probably have the wrong programming language. Java is designed to be **type safe** and the compiler can only verify that you define the type of the parameter explicitly.

Comment: What would you expect to happen if there were two different callers to `print`, one passing a `String[]` and your current `main`? What would you expect the type of the parameter to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is `list`?

```
public static void print(list) {
    for (String word : list) {
        System.out.println( word );
    }
}
```

In the context of object-oriented programming, suppose an outside class wanted to use this method.  What would it pass in here? What *could* it pass in here?  How would it know?

Fundamentally speaking, you're getting hung up on the difference between *variables* and *parameters*.  Both *must* be typed since Java is a strongly-typed language, but neither are necessarily related to one another.  You can have a parameter that's named the same as a variable you declare later for readability, but there's no mandate otherwise set anywhere for that.

To make that clear, here's the same method again:

```
public static void print(ArrayList<String> l) {
    for (String word : l) {
        System.out.println( word );
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter what your *parameter* is named, so long as it's *typed*.

Comment: Ok thank you. "What would it pass in here? What could it pass in here? How would it know?" - I'd have thought any variable type would be passed here that was declared in main. So if I initialize an Integer in main, it goes through to the method as an Integer. I'd have thought it would be up to the developer to know beforehand what variable type the method deals with, and only pass variables through of that type.

Comment: Not an unreasonable assumption, but I've been doing this professionally now for six years, and haven't written a main class except for scratch/experimental stuff.  So even that wouldn't work.  I'm glad this was helpful, though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the type in the parameter list so the type being passed in can be verified.

In this example, you may say "well, I'm only calling it once and passing it one list, so it's obvious what the type is supposed to be". What happens when it's being called from multiple places, being passed different objects? The type checker needs to know what type the function is expecting so it can throw compile time errors when the wrong type of object is supplied, and verify that the methods used on the passed object are legal for that object.

Comment: Like I mentioned in another answer, I would have thought it would be the developers responsibility to know what variable type the method deals with, and only send the correct type to the method. I suppose this makes sense in situations such as having lots of methods dealing with lots of different types, and using lots of 'try' and 'catch' blocks to route the correct type to the correct method.

Comment: @Physicsman No. As someone mentioned in the comments in your question, it will make more sense once you start writing more code. The purpose of the type checker is to catch your mistakes. You will make a lot of mistakes (everyone does), so mechanisms like the type checker are there to alleviate some of the burden. If you don't want to have to specify types everywhere, look into a dynamically typed language like Python or JavaScript. Also be prepared for more runtime errors though.

Comment: @Physicsman And just to clarify, but "no", I mean it's often unreasonable or undesirable for the developer to take the burden of stuff like type checking. Languages are a constant trade off of "how much should the language get in my way/help me prevent errors". You may need to play around with different languages to find the one that has a balance that works for you.

Comment: I'm not complaining. I'm really enjoying Java, just wanting to understand the basics as I go along so I'm asking a lot of relatively dumb questions. That makes sense though. More errors up front mean fewer errors down the line. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a strongly and statically typed languages, and it requires you to declare the type the method accepts. If you don't want the method to accept any type of list, you can do this:

```
// this method can accept an ArrayList, LinkedList, etc
public static void print(List<String> list) {
    for (String word : list) {
        System.out.println( word );
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Java");
    list.add("Python");
    list.add("Ruby");
    list.add("C++");

    print(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is a Strongly Typed programming language. Visit https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html for more information.
You can pass just a name without a type in a language like JavaScript in Java you should write type(specific word: boolean, int, double,...) and then nameOfParameter.

Comment: Ok thank you. Yes I've done a bit of JavaScript before which is why my question arose. I suppose this rule makes Java a lot clearer on what's going on.